# np.linalg.svd is giving me wrong results

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, svd, wolframalpha

so I am trying to learn how SVD work to use it in PCA (principle component analysis), but the problem is that it seam I get wrong results, I tryied using `np.linalg.svd` and this is my code :

```
A = np.array([[2, 2],
              [1, 1]])
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
print(u)
print(s)
print(v)
```

and this is the result I got :

```
[[-0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]
 [-0.4472136   0.89442719]]
[3.16227766e+00 1.10062118e-17]
[[-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
 [ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]]
```

and I tried to get SVD decomposition on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=svd%20%7B%7B2%2C%202%7D%2C%7B1%2C%201%7D%7D) and I got these results:

[image]

the magnitude of values seems correct but the sign is not correct, even I followed up with a video for a professor on [MIT OpenCourseWare on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBcLRGuAFUk) and he give these results :

[image]

which is the same magnitude answer but different signs, so what could possibly had gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Different conventions

It is a matter of a different convention for returning the matrix `v`:

From the documentation of [`numpy.linalg.svd`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html#numpy-linalg-svd) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=True, compute_uv=True, hermitian=False)
> ```
>
> Singular Value Decomposition.
>
> When a is a 2D array, and full_matrices=False, then it is factorized as **`u @ np.diag(s) @ vh = (u * s) @ vh`**, where `u` and the Hermitian transpose of `vh` are 2D arrays with orthonormal columns and s is a 1D array of a’s singular values. When `a` is higher-dimensional, SVD is applied in stacked mode as explained below.
>
> **Returns**: `u{ (…, M, M), (…, M, K) }` array Unitary array(s). The first
> `a.ndim - 2` dimensions have the same size as those of the input `a`. The
> size of the last two dimensions depends on the value of full_matrices.
> Only returned when compute_uv is True.
>
> `s(…, K)` array Vector(s) with the singular values, within each vector
> sorted in descending order. The first `a.ndim - 2` dimensions have the
> same size as those of the input `a`.
>
> **`vh`**`{ (…, N, N), (…, K, N) }` array Unitary array(s). The first `a.ndim` -
> 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input a. The size of
> the last two dimensions depends on the value of full_matrices. Only
> returned when compute_uv is True.

So to summarize: given the SVD decomposition of `x`, `x = u @ np.diag(s) @ vh` the matrices returned by `numpy.linalg.svd(x)` are `u`, `s` and `vh` where `vh` is the hermitian conjugate of `v`. Other libraries and software will instead return `v`, causing the apparent inconsistency.

It is a shame that different libraries have different conventions, this also really tripped me up the first time I had to deal with this.

### Intrinsic mathematical ambiguity on `u` and `v`

Furthermore the mathematics of the problem means that [the matrices `u` and `v` are not uniquely determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486622/how-to-distinguish-if-python-or-matlab-is-wrong-faulty?rq=1).

In order to check that the SVD is correct you need to check that the matrices `u` and `v` are indeed [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and that `x = u @ np.diag(s) @ vh`. If both conditions hold, than the SVD is correct, otherwise it isn't.

### Testing the `numpy` library

Here is some simple code to check that the implementation of the SVD library in numpy is indeed correct (of course it is, consider this a pedagogical exercise):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2, 2],
              [1, 1]])
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)

smat = np.diag(s)

def is_unary(A):
    return np.allclose(A @ A.T, np.eye(A.shape[0]))

print(f"Is u unary? {is_unary(u)}")
print(f"Is vh unary? {is_unary(vh)}")
print(f"original matrix A")
print(A)
print("Reconstructed matrix A")
print(u @ smat @ vh)

def check_svd(A, u, s, vh):
    smat = np.diag(s)
    c1 = is_unary(u)
    c2 = is_unary(vh)
    c3 = np.allclose(A, u @ smat @ vh)
    success = c1 and c2 and c3
    if not success:
        raise Exception("numpy SVD failed")

for i in range(100):
    A = np.random.rand(100, 100)
    u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    check_svd(A, u, s, vh)

print("All tests passed")
```